# Kotlin Contracts effect on another property/function

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible with Kotlin Contract to make this smartcast possible?
Assuming I have following Extension function for Maps

```
fun<K, V> Maps<K, V>.contains(k : K) : Boolean
{
    //simply check for map containing key
}
```

And after calling that method, I want this call to be casted to NotNull:

```
if(map.contains(key))
{
    map.get(key).callAnyMethod()
    //smartcast get(key) to not null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with contracts currently (side note: I'd be surprised if they cover this case). However, the standard library has you covered a couple of different ways!

Assuming you have a `Map`, you can call `containsKey` on it (sort if like you have now). Knowing that "A" in this case is not null, we can use `.getValue("A")` to get a non-null value from the map.

```
val map = mapOf("A" to "B")
if(map.containsKey("A")) {
    println(map.getValue("A").toLowerCase())
}
```

Note that if you call `.getValue()` with a value that is actually null, you will get a `NoSuchElementException`.

Another more idiomatic way to do this is to use [`let`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/idioms.html#execute-if-not-null), which will only execute the block if the value is not null:

```
map["A"]?.let { 
    println(it.toLowerCase())
}
```

In this example we could replace `["A"]` with `.get("A")` if you'd prefer.

Comment: Yes. You are right. But my question was not about how to get a Not Null value for specific key. Based on Kotlin Contracts Proposal, wrote by Dmitry Savvinov:  _In the end, all issues above are about one and the same thing: compiler doesn't know something that programmer does._ Here we know that if our call to `"A" in map.keys` returns true, then its safe to cast `map["A"]` to `String` (in your example) instead of `String?`.

Comment: Yet another (perhaps) useful use-case is to smartcast the `map["A"]` to `String`, just after putting the value for key "A" (`map["A"] = "B"`).